# What can be done to lower UE4Editor startup time?

Tags: performance, unreal-engine4

Status: the problem lowered, but compared to other users reports it persists.

I have moved to UE4.27.0 and the startup time lowered from 11 (v4.26.2) to 6 minutes! (the RAM usage lowered too!) But doesnt compare to the speed other ppl report "almost instantly"...

It is not compiling anything, not even shaders, it is like the 6th time I run it for one project.

Should I try to disable plugins? but Im new with UE and dont want to difficult my usage. Tho, for ex., I have nothing VR related to test so it could really be initially disabled.

1. HD READ SPEED? NO
   I have tested moving UE4Editor whole engine path (100GB) to a 3xSSD(Stripes), but the UE4Editor startup time remained the same. My HD were it is too, is fast but not so fast as the 3xSSD.
2. CPU USAGE? MAY BE if it could use 4 cores could solve it?
   UE4Editor startup uses A SINGLE CORE ONLY, i can confirm with htop and system monitor, it is possible to see only a single core being used 100% and it changes between the 4 cores, so only one is used at 100% per time.
   I tested this command line parameter  -USEALLAVAILABLECORES  after the project URL for UE4Editor, but nothing changed. I read that option is ignored in some machines, so may be if I patch it's usage it could work on mine?
3. GPU? no?
   a report about an integrated graphics card (weak one) says it doesnt interfere with the startup time.

LOG for UE4Editor v4.27.0 with the new biggest intervals ("..." means ommited log lines to make it easier to read; "!(interval in seconds)" is just to easy reading it (no ommitted lines here)):

```
[2021.09.15-23.38.20:677][  0]LogHAL: Linux SourceCodeAccessSettings: NullSourceCodeAccessor
!22s
[2021.09.15-23.38.42:780][  0]LogTcpMessaging: Initializing TcpMessaging bridge
[2021.09.15-23.38.42:782][  0]LogUdpMessaging: Initializing bridge on interface 0.0.0.0:0 to multicast group 230.0.0.1:6666.
!16s
[2021.09.15-23.38.58:158][  0]LogPython: Using Python 3.7.7
...
[2021.09.15-23.39.01:817][  0]LogImageWrapper: Warning: PNG Warning: Duplicate iCCP chunk
!75s
[2021.09.15-23.40.16:951][  0]SourceControl: Source control is disabled
...
[2021.09.15-23.40.26:867][  0]LogAndroidPermission: UAndroidPermissionCallbackProxy::GetInstance
!16s
[2021.09.15-23.40.42:325][  0]LogAudioCaptureCore: Display: No Audio Capture implementations found. Audio input will be silent.
...
[2021.09.15-23.41.08:207][  0]LogInit: Transaction tracking system initialized
!9s
[2021.09.15-23.41.17:513][  0]BlueprintLog: New page: Editor Load
!23s
[2021.09.15-23.41.40:396][  0]LocalizationService: Localization service is disabled
...
[2021.09.15-23.41.45:457][  0]MemoryProfiler: OnSessionChanged
!13s
[2021.09.15-23.41.58:497][  0]LogCook: Display: CookSettings for Memory: MemoryMaxUsedVirtual 0MiB, MemoryMaxUsedPhysical 16384MiB, MemoryMinFreeVirtual 0MiB, MemoryMinFreePhysical 1024MiB
```

SPECS:
I'm using ubuntu 20.04.
My CPU is 4 cores 3.6GHz.
GeForce GT 710 1GB.

Related question but for older UE4: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/987852/view.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use Linux. Check these forums, the problem could be in **glibc** library
https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/ue5-linux-slow-editor-launch/493052
https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/linux-editor-launching-too-slow/351291/20

> Thanks for the reply, you are correct on glibc being the problem. From
> my limited research it seems an official patch may take some time. If
> you cannot wait there is a patch available from a PPA, check this
> thread for details Apply DSO sorting patches to glibc in Linux images
> · Issue #177 · adamrehn/ue4-docker · GitHub 113.
>
> I have installed it and it has reduced editor load times (for me) from
> over 4 minutes to just a few seconds :grinning:

Answer (score -2):

Unreal Engine needs a high-end pc with a lot of RAM, fast SSD's, a good CPU and a medium graphic card. First of all there are **always** some shaders that needs to be compiled from the engine, and a lot of assets to be loaded in the startup time. As I can see you're on Linux you are probably using a self-compiled Unreal Engine version.... not the best thing to do for a newbie, because this may cause several problems on load time, startup, compiling and a lot of other stuff. If it's the first times you're using Unreal, try using it on Windows, it's all easier.

Comment: sorry if I make you angry trying to help you, but here the one who has not read the full message is you, I said that a certain amount of shaders must be compiled at every startup, not just the first time.  Also, the fact that unreal is available for Linux doesn't mean it's as easy as the Windows version.  Don't ask questions if you already know the answers. In addition, the required performance is even higher than what I have listed, as more ram is required on the official Unreal site for Ubuntu